# extract GUID and other attributes from pipeline within ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm wanting to create my own log file to store various attributes each time a pipeline is executed.  How do I add a step to my pipeline that records the pipeline GUID, timestamp for starting the process, timestamp for completion, completion status, successful record counts, error record counts, etc.?

I'm thinking I'd want need an output for different statuses but I'm not sure what to actually specify for the code to capture the different elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use the PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun?view=azurermps-6.13.0) and direct the output to the desired logging mechanism.

Example Output:

> ```
> ResourceGroupName : ADF
> DataFactoryName   : WikiADF
> ActivityName      : MyWebActivity
> PipelineRunId     : f288712d-fb08-4cb8-96ef-82d3b9b30621
> PipelineName      : DPWikisample
> Input             : {method, url, headers, body...}
> Output            : {operationstatus}
> LinkedServiceName :
> ActivityRunStart  : 9/14/2017 12:20:57 AM
> ActivityRunEnd    : 9/14/2017 12:21:00 AM
> DurationInMs      : 2768
> Status            : Succeeded
> Error             : {errorCode, message, failureType, target}
> ```

For ADFv1, the applicable cmdlet is: [Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactoryrun?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Comment: OK, I can see how this would work but how do I initiate the cmdlet within my ADFv2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do what I needed for now by setting variables within the pipeline since I didn't get any additional feedback from the previous user